# Hide column in UWP DataGrid

Tags: uwp, datagrid, windows-community-toolkit

I am using the DataGrid control from Windows Community Toolkit for UWP, but I can't find a solution to dynamically hide or show columns.

`Runtime error: Failed to assign to property 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Ui.Controls.DataGridColumn.Visibility'`

```
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="TradeGrid">
  <controls:DataGridTextColumn
    x:Uid="DataColumnPositionContract"
    Width="SizeToCells"
    Binding="{Binding Path=TradePosition.Contract.Name}"
    Tag="Contract"
    Visibility="{Binding ElementName=TradeGrid, Path=DataContext.IsContractVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConv}}" />
</controls:DataGrid>
```

The view model structure looks like:

PageViewModel (bound to page)

- List of items (itemsource of DataGrid)
- Column visibility properties

ItemViewModel (DataContext of a column)

- Item properties

The converter is the converter provided by the toolkit. The boolean property to bind is not part of the DataContext of the column (ItemViewModel). I need to access the parent view model (PageViewModel) to get the property.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to bind to the `Visibility` property of a DataGridColumn?

I am open for other solutions if the binding is not possible this way in UWP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I cannot reproduce the **Runtime error** based on the code provided by you.

Secondly, the `Visibility` property of `DataGridTextColumn` is not a dependency property from the [source code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGridColumn.cs#L562), so the binding will not work.

So, you could try to set the value of `Visibility` property to `Visibility.Collapsed` or `Visibility.Visible` directly when you know the target columns to hide or show.

**Update:**

If you want to set the `Visibility` property directly, you need to know the index(such as the “0”) of the target column and write the code in a method in code-behind such as a `Click` event handler on a button, like this:

```
dataGrid1.Columns.ElementAt(0).Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

You can use **{x:Bind}** extension instead of **{Binding}** extension to show or hide columns in a `DataGrid`, and the binding source class need to implement  [System.ComponentModel.InotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth#binding-source), like this

```
<controls:DataGridTextColumn 
            ……    Visibility="{x:Bind SourceClass.Visible,Mode=OneWay}"  />
```

You can change the value of `SourceClass.Visible` to show or hide a column at runtime.

Comment: How can I set the `Visibility` property directly? In a method in code-behind? Is there no way to use a binding to show/hide columns in a DataGrid on demand at runtime?

Comment: I update the previous answer, you could check if it can meet your requirements.

Comment: I went with the code-behind solution as my view models would need some refactoring before I could use `{x:Bind}`. It's working, so I could reach my goal!